# (DC.JS) how to see only one year value with pie chart(i mean year filter)

Tags: javascript

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HQ61.png)

var ndx           = crossfilter(experiments),

```
  runDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.name;})
  speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.price;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `filter(function)` to filter out certain values using a function. In your case, you can use:

```
data_arr.filter((date_str) => new Date(date_str).getFullYear() == new Date().getFullYear())
```

to get all values in the current year.

Comment: This is my chart making function. Not work see only year help me.

Comment: chart
    .width(308)
    .height(220)
    .slicesCap(4)
    .innerRadius(30)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .legend(dc.legend())
    .ordinalColors(["#8A8AD6", "#00BBDE", "#FE6672", "#EEB058"])

    // workaround for #703: not enough data is accessible through .label() to display percentages
    .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
            return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
        })
    });